# Swift Switch case: Default will never be executed warning

Tags: switch-statement, swift2

On Xcode 7b2 with Swift 2 code, I have following:

In a switch case the compiler returns the following warning :

```
Default will never be executed
```

The code :

```
switch(type) {
  case .foo:
    return "foo"
  case .bar:
    return "bar"
  case .baz:
    return "baz"
  default:
    return "?"
}
```

Why would there be a warning ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I just understood why : 
The object I "switched" on is an `enum` and my `enum` only has 3 entries : `.foo`, `.bar`, `baz`.

The compiler gets that there is no need of a default because every possibility of the `enum` gets tested.

Comment: Can you mark your answer as correct, please so that everyone can see that your question was answered.

Comment: perfect solution.

Answer (score 10):

I think this warning violates the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). When you add an enum value later, the default will be missing, and you can't predict what your code will do. So you have to change also this place. Anyway, using switch() at all violates this principle.

Comment: As soon as you add another value you're code will stop compiling. The compiler throws an error at each switch statement where the cases are being considered. This comment is a bit late, but hopefully still useful.

Answer (score 4):

This could be because `type` is a enum with 3 cases and the compiler knows that the switch statement is exhaustive so you don't need a `default` statement in order to handle all possible cases.